# operator new(n) versus new unsigned char[n] for placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, placement-new

I'm allocating memory that will later be used for constructing objects with placement `new`. Should I be using `operator new(n)`, or should I be using `new unsigned char[n]`? Why?

Comment: I think either would do just fine.

Comment: @sftrabbit: So there's no difference, in terms of alignment, semantics, performance, or something like that?

Comment: @Mehrdad *"semantics"* - Exactly there's the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Factors:

- `new[]` must be matched with `delete[]` / `new()` with `delete`
- They *communicate* different things.  `operator new(n)` is a request for memory for unspecified purposes, whereas `new unsigned char[n]` loosely implies intent to store characters there.

The array form may be *slightly* worse performance / efficiency wise - exact details depending on your implementation:

> 5.3.4/12 new T[5] results in a call of operator new where x is a non-neagtive unspecified value representing array allocation overhead: the result of the new-expression will be offset by this amount from the value returned by `operator new[]`....

BTW - neither are initialised:

- `operator new()` returns a `void*` to uninitialised memory: see 3.7.4.1/2 "There are no constraints on the contents of the allocated storage on return from the allocation function", whereas 5.3.4/15 says "a new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows: if the new-initializer is ommitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5)"; 8.5/6 says only class types default constructors provide initialisation.

Answer (score 5):

The former returns a pointer to some storage area. The latter returns a pointer to the first element of an array with some *objects* in it. If you need storage, use the one that gives storage and not objects.

Comment: What's the difference? Aren't they both uninitialized? Or are you just saying it's a readability issue?

Comment: @Elazar No. No object gets initialized with `operator new[n]`. `new unsigned char[n]` default-initializes an array of `unsigned char` (and the default initialization of `unsigned char` performs no initialization).

Comment: @Elazar: neither are initialised - Standard references provided in my answer.

Comment: I'm so confused, who's Elazar? o_O

Comment: @Mehrdad someone who has since removed their comment.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ah lol okay, I thought you were responding to me with the wrong name, since I didn't see any other person commenting lol.